# Check datatype of column after applying function MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time

I want to know datatype of column after using a function.

```
SELECT timediff(date('2020-10-01 00:00:00'), date('2020-10-00 00:00:00'));
```

After using timediff function what datatype is it? I've looked at the doc to search for output datatype of a function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html but could not find, Also it would be inefficient to memorize which function outputs what datatype, so I would like to perform an operation creating new column and know its exact datatype.

When I connect MySQL to python and check its datatype it is timedelta but is it also called timedelta in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After using timediff function what datatype is it? I've looked at the doc to search for output datatype of a function but could not find.

Well, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) sure gives you the answer (emphasis mine):

> `TIMEDIFF()` returns `expr1 − expr2` **expressed as a `time` value**.

And further:

> The result returned by `TIMEDIFF()` is limited to the range allowed for `TIME` values. Alternatively, you can use either of the functions `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, both of which return integers.

Comment: Oh yeah I should look more closely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `timediff` function will give you output in `TIME` type which is a type in `mysql`. However, to make sure for the output of the type you can cast it into the type like below,

```
select cast(timediff(date('2020-10-02 00:00:00'), date('2020-10-00 00:00:00')) as TIME);
```

To know more about `TIME` type click [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html). Know about `CAST()` click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp).

You can add by following sample query,

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
ADD COLUMN `colTime` TIME NULL ;
```